# C Array of const unsigned char[][]

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, constants

I'm a little turned around on the exact syntax for doing this.  I have one array defined as such:

```
const unsigned char ARR[SIZE][SIZE] = {...}
```

and I want to have it in an array so I can do something to the effect of

```
ARR2[0] = ARR
```

I've tried `const unsigned char ARR2[][SIZE][SIZE] = {ARR}` and `const unsigned char* ARR2[SIZE][SIZE] = {ARR}`, but neither of those worked.  Can someone point out the correct syntax for having a constant array of constant two dimensional arrays of unsigned characters?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve: can you post the code where you try to use `ARR` and this `ARR2` thingy?

Comment: Do you mean that you want an array of `[SIZE][SIZE]` arrays, or an array of pointers to `[SIZE][SIZE]` arrays?

Comment: In other words, do you intend for `ARR2[0]` to point to `ARR`, or to itself be an array initialized with the contents of `ARR`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment to haccks' answer, it sounds like you want this:

```
const unsigned char ARR[SIZE][SIZE] = {...};
const unsigned char (*ARR2[])[SIZE][SIZE] = {&ARR};
```

If you want `ARR2` itself to be `const`, that would be like this:

```
const unsigned char (* const ARR2[])[SIZE][SIZE] = {&ARR};
```

It should perhaps also be noted that you cannot use this abomination to access `ARR[x][y]` as `ARR2[0][x][y]`, but need to do `(*ARR2[0])[x][y]` (or, equivalently, `ARR2[0][0][x][y]`).

Another corollary that might be noteworthy is that you cannot assign `ARR2` with `ARR2[0] = ARR`, but you need explicitly to do `ARR2[0] = &ARR` (at least to avoid warnings). The reason is that `ARR` degenerates to a pointer *to its first element*, that is, a `const unsigned char *` whose value is `&ARR[0][0]`, whereas `ARR2[0]` expects to be assigned a `const unsigned char (*)[SIZE][SIZE]`, which is obtained with `&ARR`. While the pointer value is identical in both cases, the types aren't.

Comment: This is technically correct, but seems way ahead of the OPs skill level. As a matter of fact, it looks like a compiler conformance test.

Comment: Yeah, I realized when I started writing ARR2 that it was going to be a little bit of a mess.  I needed to have an array of arrays, and needed each of the arrays to have their own header files for portability reasons.

I understand what's happening here; I guess I was under the mistaken impression that any time you use an array, it's converted to a reference.

Comment: @user2752635: Not sure, but from your comment to Sergio's answer, it also sound like you may be under the mistaken impression that variable initialization is the same as (or at least similar to) variable assignment, which can be quite far from the truth.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you are trying to achieve is impossible since left operand of assignment operator can be only of arithmetic, structure / union or pointer type, but not an array one. See here for details: [6.5.16.1 Simple assignment](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.pdf).

So the only way for you is only `memcpy()`'ing.

Comment: I don't understand.  `const unsigned char ARR[SIZE][SIZE] = {...}` compiles fine.  I can use ARR in my code.  Setting an array equal to something isn't the problem, the problem is the typing.

That might be a feature of gcc but I can definitely initialize an array that way.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
const unsigned char (* ARR2)[SIZE] = ARR;
```

---

You mentioned in your comment that you want `ARR2` to be an array that can hold array `ARR` as it's first element but, **this is not possible**. `ARR` is an array and it will converted to pointer to it's first element expect when it's an operand of unary `&` and `sizeof` operator.

Comment: I'm not trying to have a pointer to ARR.  I'm trying to have an array, of which the first index points to ARR.

Comment: @user2752635; Updated the answer.